# useLocation hook undefined on startup: TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

I am writing a typescript React application that will log a user in and update the `Dashboard` component to display the user information, such as their access tokens and their name. I am using the `useLocation` hook to pass the state from the fetch request in the `LoginCallback` component to display it in the Dashboard component.

The problem I am having is that on startup the Dashboard component won't render as the state is undefined because it hasn't been passed by the `LoginCallback` component yet, giving me a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`.

I'm wondering if there is a way of assigning a default value for the `state.authenticated` value, any help would be greatly appreciated! The code for the components are below:

Index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.tsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Navbar, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginCallback from './components/LoginCallback';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar className='bg-dark'>
          <Navbar.Brand className='text-white' href="#home">
          <img
            src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/AgileInventoryLogo.png"}
            width="159"
            height="50"
            className="d-inline-block align-top"
            alt="React Bootstrap logo"
          />
          </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
        <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
        {name !== 'null' ?
          <Navbar.Text  className='text-white'>Not signed in: <Button  className='text-white' href='/login' variant="outline-info">Sign In</Button></Navbar.Text> :
          <Navbar.Text  className='text-white'>Signed in as: <a  className='text-white' href="#login">Mark Otto</a></Navbar.Text> }
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={() => { window.location.href = 'http://localhost:9090/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client2&scope=read'; return null; }} />
          <Route path="/oauth_callback" component={LoginCallback} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <Dashboard/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Dashboard.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

const Dashboard = () => {
    const {state} = useLocation();
    // COULD USE REDUX TO STORE USER INFO ACROSS COMPONENTS
    return (
        <div>
            <p> Dashboard </p>
            { state.authenticated ?
                <div>
                    <p>Authenticated</p>
                    <p> stored access token: {state.access_token} </p>
                    <p> refresh token: {state.refresh_token}</p>
                    <p> user: {state.user.user_name}</p>
                </div>
                            :
                <p>Not Authenticated</p>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

LoginCallback.tsx:

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

const LoginCallback: FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ location }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const code = (location.search.match(/code=([^&]+)/) || [])[1];
    const qParams = [
      `grant_type=authorization_code`,
      `scope=read`,
      `code=${code}`
    ].join("&");
    fetch(`http://localhost:9090/oauth/token?${qParams}`, {
    // credentials: "include",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic Y2xpZW50MjpzZWNyZXQy'
    }})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      var decode = jwt_decode(response.access_token);
      history.push({pathname: '/', state: {
        authenticated: true,
        user: decode,
        access_token: response.access_token,
        token_type: response.token_type,
        refresh_token: response.refresh_token,
        expires_in: response.expires_in,
        scope: response.scope
      }});
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
  }, []);
  return null;
};

export default LoginCallback;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's Because you used `<Dashboard/>` Component outside of a `<Router>` wrapper.

`useLocation` hook needs to be called in a component which is a child of `<Router>` component.

`Edited`

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  // COULD USE REDUX TO STORE USER INFO ACROSS COMPONENTS
  return (
    <div>
      <p> Dashboard </p>
      { state && state.authenticated ? (
        <div>
          <p>Authenticated</p>
          <p> stored access token: {state.access_token} </p>
          <p> refresh token: {state.refresh_token}</p>
          <p> user: {state.user.user_name}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Not Authenticated</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Taghi, thanks for your reply! I moved the dashboard component inside the Router wrapper, but I'm still getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticated' of undefined`

Comment: this is another question though. you need to check to see if you're passing the state to the `location` or not

Comment: yes true, I am passing the state from the LoginCallback component when the user logs in, but on startup it hasnt been passed yet, so I need to pass an initial value in or set a default value or something but I'm unsure how to do that

Comment: just add another check for `state` like I mentioned above. and if the answer is helpful to you try to accept the answer

Comment: Thats works! Thank you so much I really appreciate it

Comment: @a-smith96 Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and it turned out to be multiple versions of react-router-dom.....incase anyone tries the above and it doesn't work. You can add an "overrides" section to the package.json. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides