# Cannot read property 'location' of undefined (useLocation())

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm trying to use useLocation() I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined. I perfectly import useLocation from react-router-dom but this error happens. How can I fix it?

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getCurrentUser, handleSignOut } from './components/login/HandleLogin';
import Login from './components/login/Login';
import Booking from './components/booking/Booking';
import Header from './components/shared/header/Header';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import PrivateRoute from './components/privateRoute/PrivateRoute';
import Search from './components/search/Search';

export const UserContext = createContext();
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [bookingInfo, setBookingInfo] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentUser().then(res => {
      setUser(res)
    })
  }, [])
  const signOUtUser = () => {
    handleSignOut().then(res => {
      setUser(res)
    })
  }
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser, bookingInfo, setBookingInfo, signOUtUser }}>
      <div className={`${location.pathname === '/' || location.pathname.includes('booking') ? "home" : ""}`}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/booking/:id" component={Booking} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/search/:id">
            <Search />
          </PrivateRoute>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

show the error location is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried consoling the location const that you are declaring? Does that return you undefined as well?

Comment: just don't render anything when location is undefined, since your component depends on it

Comment: @bel3atar got it. thanks

Comment: May be a duplicate question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65491504/uselocation-hook-undefined-on-startup-typeerror-cannot-read-property-location)

Answer (score 0):

use **BrowserRouter** .

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
```